# How to render a UNORM formatted texture to an sRGB DirectX11 swapchain?

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, virtual-reality, openxr

I'm writing a DirectX 11 OpenXR app. OpenXR creates the DX11 swapchain with a format of `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB` (the device doesn't support non sRGB formats).

The problem I have is that I need to render a video texture. And `IMFMediaEngine::TransferVideoFrame()` won't work unless the texture is in a non sRGB format like `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`. So if I use the UNORM texture format for the video frame it works.

The problem is that in the headset the colors of the texture are off. They are too bright. I suspect converting them from sRGB->Linear inside the pixel shader would make them look like they are supposed to. But I'm not sure what is happening.

I'm a bit confused about how to handle this situation where the swapchain (sRGB) is created by OpenXR and it does the presenting but I have to sample from UNORM textures.

Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: Create a ``DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`` render target, use IMFMediaEngine on that. Then render a quad using that video sampling from that texture with the render target set to the SRGB backbuffer. The hardware should take care of the conversion assuming your source data is in linear format. See [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thank you for the help I really appreciate it. Are you saying I should create a `ID3D11RenderTargetView` on the texture that will receive the video frame and that's what IMFMediaEngine should use to write to instead of to the `ID3D11Texture2D` directly? The transfer frame code I am looking at: https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/blob/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/VideoTextureUWP/MediaEnginePlayer.cpp#L227 takes a texture rather than a RTV. How would it need to change to use an RTV?

Comment: You create a ID3D12Texture2D resource. You can create both a SRV and a RTV for the same resource, or you can just create a SRV for it. See [this tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Writing-custom-shaders) which does a bunch of render to texture examples.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I'm using DX11 not 12. So I'm not sure why I'd use a ID3D12Texture2D. I do have a ID3D11Texture2D with both an SRV & RTV. However I'm failing to understand how `IMFMediaEngine::TransferVideoFrame ` can work with an RTV. I see how it works with an ID3D11Texture2D but that's what I've already been doing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I meant D3D11Texture2D. If you look at the rest of that sample, you'll see it does exactly what I recommended. You don't pass the swapchain backbuffer as the target of transfer video frame, but instead your own texture. You then render using that texure ONTO the swapchain backbuffer.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I think that's what I have been doing except because the texture that MediaFoundation renders to is UNORM and the swapchain is sRGB the colors were wrong. I found If I make 2 textures one UNORM and one sRGB & have MediaFoundation render to the UNORM tex. I can do `context->CopyResource(sRGBtexture, unormTexture);` then if I render with the SRV of sRGBtexture if will display correctly. Is this what you meant? I wonder if it would be faster to not copy the video texture and instead have the pixel shader correct the colors though. Which would you suggest? Or am I being dumb :)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Also keep in mind there is no Present() being called here because OpenXR does the presenting. So if any "magic" normally happens with a D3D Present it wouldn't occur.

Comment: Maybe you should read [this blog post](http://filmicworlds.com/blog/linear-space-lighting-i-e-gamma/). When you sample from an SRV with the ``_SRGB`` format, it is degamma'd from ~2.2 to linear (1.0). When you write to a RTV with a ``_SRGB`` format it is gamma'd from linear (1.0) to ~2.2. This is all done by the hardware automatically, so you shouldn't have to write a custom pixel shader.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Yes that's why it works when MF renders to the UNORM texture and then I copy that texture to an sRGB texture and then sample from the SRV of the sRGB texture. But because MF  can only transfer a frame to a "Raw" UNORM texture (not using an RTV) I have to either copy that UNORM texture -> sRGB texture (& then sample from its SRV) OR do the correction in the shader. Right?

Comment: You can create an ``_UNORM_SRGB`` SRV or RTV for a resource with a ``_UNORM`` format that otherwise matches.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Had tried that but get : `R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB is invalid, when creating a View; the Resource was already created with a fully qualified Format, which is not castable (0x1c, R8G8B8A8_UNORM)`

Comment: What version and build # of Windows are you using?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Windows 10 Home Version: 20H2 Build: 19042.685

Comment: Well, that looks like an over-validation to me. Oh well. I guess you should do the gamma work in the pixel shader when rendering the video texture to the backbuffer after all

Comment: OK, thank you for your time on this.

Comment: Hello @ChuckWalbourn. Would it be possible to do a copy from UNORM buffer (that contains gamma corrected data but cannot be flagged as SRGB) to a TYPELESS temporary buffer, and then copy that to the SRGB swapchain with the right DXGI_FORMAT?
Would it be worse in performance than rendering a quad?

Comment: You could try it, but I don't know what the validation layer is likely to do. Rendering a quad is probably the fastest option.